# Classification of Elliptic singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

For a $K_3$ surface $X$, if  there exists a holomorphic surjective map $X\to \mathbb P^1$, with elliptic fibres, i.e. for any generic point on $\mathbb P^1$ whose fiber is diffeomorphic to a torus $\mathbb T^2$.

> **Q**: Where we can find the classification of the singularities(the fiber over some point is not a standard manifold, $\mathbb T^2$) of the map $X\to \mathbb P^1$?

Comment: This is a very classical question, which has been answered by Kodaira more than 50 years ago. You'll find an account for instance in *Compact complex surfaces* by Barth-Hulek-Peters-Van de Ven.

Comment: By the way, in algebraic geometry *elliptic singularity* has a different meaning than *singular fibre of an elliptic fibration*.